# Sections of website only available to company network users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, authorization

What is the best way to authorize access to sections of the external facing website based on internal(inside company network) or external(web) user.

Is IP Address sniffing the only way(dont really like it. :S). Can we use Active Directory to check for internal users at the same time not affecting web users?.

The website does not need authentication(we dont have a login screen).

(ASP.Net MVC3, .Net 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you think of it as two separate websites - an internal intranet and an external site.  This gives you more flexibility in deployment, and reduces the risk that a problem on one site will affect the other.  If you deploy your internal site to a server without an external IP then it will by default be restricted to only those users within your network.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a login, then IP address detection is the easiest, but not foolproof way of achieving what you ask.

You could also deny anonymous access but allow integrated auth to the internal sections. That would mean only folks authenticated to your domain could access the site. anyone else would be denied & you wouldn't need to add any sort of login to the app.

Simon